QTextCodec compile error with cyrillic symbols
Sometime I have compile error, when use cyrilic symbols with QTextCodec.
I use msvs 2019 and qt6.
I use code Page 1251.
Compile error description : "newline in constant".
Compile error code: C2001.
Doc for this error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2001?view=msvc-170
auto codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");

QString exitHeaderOk   =  codec->toUnicode("Выход "); // success

QString exitHeaderError   =  codec->toUnicode("Выход"); // error


What is a reason of this  behaviour ?

Please share some more debugging information that helps others to reproduce your issue. What is the code page of your source code file? What error exactly do you observe?

You can store Выход inside a QString without calling QTextCodec, which BTW is deprecated. What is your reason for doing it this way?

@Atmo I use Code page-1251 in my current project. I have to use QTextCodec to avoid encoding bugs. To solve the compile error , I change encoding to  UTF-8, code page 65001
